# How to override "Minimum font size" in Firefox affecting text within svg?

Tags: css, firefox, svg, accessibility

When Firefox has "Minimum font size" set to 15, text within a `svg` becomes super large.

Haven't found anything similar to my problem. Appreciate any insight on this issue!

Note: It's an `img` where the `src` is a `.svg` file. https://codepen.io/amyrlam/pen/QPRmoY

Expected: Text within `svg` appears as normal.
[image: expected]

Actual result: Text within `svg` is blown up.
[image: actual]

How to set minimum font size: Firefox > Preferences > Language and Appearance > Fonts & Colors > Advanced > set Minimum font size to 15

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this by changing my minimum font size in Firefox.

Comment: @sean I'm on Firefox 66.0.3. When I go to https://codepen.io/amyrlam/pen/QPRmoY with the minimum font size 15 set, I get this: [firefox](https://i.imgur.com/maAb1qW.png)

Comment: Converting the text into paths would solve the display issue, but then the text wouldn't be selectable or accessible. What program generated this SVG?

Comment: You'd have to submit.a patch to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=935056). **Warning:** if you're not going to submit.a patch please don't comment on the bug.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an example generated by [`svg-term-cli`](https://github.com/marionebl/svg-term-cli/).  As Robert Longson indicates in the comments above, this is a Firefox bug/regression to SVG text scaling when minimum font size is set.  If I understand the discussion correctly, FF incorrectly interprets a size of "5px" *in the SVG coordinate space, before viewport scaling to final rendered size* as being below the minimum font size.  Thus "5px" is scaled up to e.g. "15pt" on the SVG `text` elements, *then* scaled again for the actual SVG viewport and BIG LETTERS ENSUE.

Given that the FF bug has had a series of patch attempts that were backed out for causing other intermittent regressions, I'll suggest a workaround from the SVG side: attempt to adjust the scaling in the SVG's coordinate space to prevent the Firefox bug from triggering.  E.g. multiply the SVG coordinate system sizes by some scaling factor, so every text element is always "bigger" than reasonable minimum font size settings.  There's [a tracking issue](https://github.com/marionebl/svg-term-cli/issues/39#issuecomment-496246715) on `svg-term-cli`; I've added similar details to that discussion.